# S3 Request time too skewed

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently building an application in C# that makes use of the AWS SDK for uploading files to S3.

However, I have some users who are getting the "Request time too skewed" error when the application tries to upload a file.

I understand the problem is that the user's clock is out of sync, however, it is difficult to expect a user to change this, so I was wondering, is there any way to get this error not to occur (any .NET functionality to get accurate time with NTP or the alike?)

Below the current code I am using to upload files.

```
var _s3Config = new AmazonS3Config { ServiceURL = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" };
var _awsCredentials = new SessionAWSCredentials(credentials.AccessKeyId, credentials.SecretAccessKey, credentials.SessionToken);
var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(_awsCredentials, _s3Config);
var putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
{
  BucketName = "my.bucket.name",
  Key = "/path/to/file.txt",
  FilePath = "/path/to/local/file.txt"
};
putRequest.StreamTransferProgress += OnUploadProgress;
var response = await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking this question you have probably taken AWS as far as you can go with the provided code sample.

I have found most of the async upload functionality provided by AWS to be more theoretical, or better suited for limited use cases, instead of being production ready for the mainstream- especially end users with all those browsers and operating systems:)

I would recommend rethinking the design of your program: create your own C# upload turnstile and keep the AWS SDK upload functions running as a background process (or sysadmin function) so that AWS servers are handling only your server's time.

Answer (score 4):

Getting the time from a timeserver is actually the easier part of your challenge.  There is no built-in C# functionality that I'm aware of to get an accurate time from a time server, but a quick search yields plenty of sample code for NTP clients.  I found a good comprehensive sample at dotnet-snippets.com (probably overkill for your case), and a very streamlined version on Stack Overflow in a page titled "**How to Query an NTP Server using C#?**".  The latter looks like it might be effective in your case, since all you need is a reasonably accurate idea of the current time.

Now on to the real challenge: using that time with Amazon S3.  First, some background, as it's important to understand why this is happening.  The time skew restriction is intended to protect against replay attacks, as noted here:
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html

Because of this, Amazon built the current timestamp into the authentication signature used in the AWS SDK when constructing the HTTP(S) request.  However, the SDK always uses the current time (there's no way to override it in the SDK methods):
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/AWSSDK_DotNet35/Amazon.Runtime/Internal/Auth/AWS3Signer.cs#L119

Note that in all cases, the SDK uses AWSSDKUtils.FormattedCurrentTimestampRFC822 as the timestamp, and there's no way for the caller to pass a different value into the method.

So this leaves you with two options that I can see:

1. Bypass the Amazon SDK and construct your own HTTP requests using the time you retrieve from an NTP server.  This is doable but not easy.  Amazon discourages this approach because the SDK provides a lot of helpful wrappers to ensure that you're using the API as a whole correctly, handling a lot of the tedious message processing that you have to do yourself if you go straight HTTP.  It also helps with a lot of the error handling and ensuring that things get cleaned up properly if a transfer is interrupted.
2. Clone the Amazon SDK git repository and create your own fork with a modification to allow you to pass in the current time.  This would also be difficult, as you'd have to work out a way to pass the time down through several layers of API objects.  And you'd lose the benefit of being able to easily update to a new SDK when one is available.

Sorry there's no easy answer for you, but I hope this helps.